# My Indian passport renewed but not yet updated on Austalian PR Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, passport-renewals, australian-residents

**Background**

I have an Australian PR visa (subclass 189) and an Indian passport. I have recently renewed my passport because it was due to expire.
I have submitted my new details via : https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/contact-details on 28 Aug 2019 but my new passport details have not been updated yet. (*Been trying to contact them to sort it out*)

**Problem:**

I will be going out of the country for holiday for a couple of weeks.

**Question:**

What will happen when I return to Australia but my new passport details haven't been updated in their system ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely run into trouble *leaving* Australia, since your new passport is not in Australia's system.  However, the good news is that (at last check) they can update your passport details at the border if needed, and after this returning is not a problem.

I would suggest trying to contact them again a few times, by phone instead of emailing, and then showing up the airport nice and early if you can't get it sorted.  Bringing your old passport if you still have it would also be helpful.

Section 2.2 of this [document](https://www.abf.gov.au/help-and-support-subsite/files/advance-passenger-processing.pdf) is the government reference.

Comment: thanks that sounds like a good backup option , would you happen to have a link to an article on the government site? I can't seem to find much info on this.

Comment: @NigelFds I don't think there is a government site that confirms they can make changes at airport immigration, and I'd hesitate to rely on this myself, but I can tell you my wife has done it once.

Comment: @NigelFds Section 2.2 of [this document](https://www.abf.gov.au/help-and-support-subsite/files/advance-passenger-processing.pdf) is the government reference. Basically the airline check-in agent can call the BOC to update your passport details over the phone.

Comment: @k2moo4 Nice find!

Comment: @k2moo4 awesome .... @ jjpatokal I've added the document to your answer